# How to serialize an assertion with spring-security-saml2-service-provider

Tags: spring-security, spring-saml, opensaml

I’ve an existing Spring Boot project used to authenticate an Angular SPA with SAML.

The dependencies included in the Spring Boot project are:

-**spring-boot-starter-security** (version 2.6.6)

-**spring-security-saml2-core** (version 1.0.10.RELEASE)

I’ve replaced the **spring-security-saml2-core** with **spring-security-saml2-service-provider**

because spring-security-saml2-core is being superseded by the SAML feature set in Spring Security Core and the configuration it’s more simplified.

Exist a similar feature (see : Section 9.5
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-saml/docs/1.0.x/reference/html/configuration-sso.html#configuration-authentication-assertion)

to serialize the SAML assertion response with **spring-security-saml2-service-provider** ?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved. Saml2Authentication returns the SAML response object, as decoded XML (see: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/saml2/provider/service/authentication/Saml2Authentication.html)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).